# How do I get a list of models to use over Odoo/OpenERP XML-RPC?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

I have found [some](http://snipplr.com/view/17608/openerp-xmlrpc-web-services-crud-example/) examples using `model = 'res.partner'` but I want to work with other models. I tried res.product but that didn't work. How can I get a list of usable models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ir.model` contains a list of all models. `ir` stands for information retrieval.

A very convenient way to get a better grasp of Odoo's XML-RPC is by using [ERPpeek](https://github.com/tinyerp/erppeek):

```
sudo pip install -U erppeek
erppeek  --server=https://example.com -d your_db -u admin -p password
your_db >>> models()
```

Answer (score 1):

All the models in Odoo are also tables in the postgresql database. So you also could get the description of the PostgreSQL database via autodoc.

```
postgresql_autodoc -h localhost -p 5432 -d database -U user
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [Openerp Proxy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openerp_proxy/) lib t work via xmlrpc. It has IPython shell to debug data.

In Your case to get list of all available models just install and run openerp_proxy shell:

```
$ pip install openerp_proxy
$ openerp_proxy
```

connect to database:

```
>>> db = session.connect()
```

and print list of all models:

```
>>> db.registered_objects
# Here will be printed list of all registered models in database
```

to search for specific models You can do something like this:

```
>>> for model in sdb['ir.model'].search_records([('model','like','res.partner')]):
        print "{0:<20}\t{1:<30}".format(model.name, model.model)

    Partner                 res.partner                   
    Bank Accounts           res.partner.bank              
    Bank Account Type       res.partner.bank.type         
    Bank type fields        res.partner.bank.type.field   
    Partner Categories      res.partner.category          
    res.partner.title       res.partner.title
```

(for more info read the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/openerp_proxy/))

And in future versions some syntax sugar will be implemented)